# Prove that $A$ in invertible through characteristic polynomial: $x^{500}+x^{100}-x+4$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, characteristic-polynomial

Let $A$ be a matrix with charecteristic polynomial $$p(x)=x^{500}+x^{100}-x+4$$
Prove that $A$ is invertible.

I'm very lost with this one, because I don't know how to calculate the eigenvalues, I thought  that I maybe have to prove that the polynomial has differents eigenvalues, but I'm not sure.

Comment: A matrix is invertible if and only if its determinant is nonzero. We also know that the constant coefficient of the characteristic polynomial of a matrix is equal to its determinant. In this case, the constant coefficient is 4 which is nonzero hence the matrix is invertible.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

By the Cayley–Hamilton theorem,$$A^{500}+A^{100}-A+4\operatorname{Id}=0;$$in other words,$$A.(A^{499}+A^{99}-\operatorname{Id})=-4\operatorname{Id}.$$Can you take it from here?

Comment: So, we have that $(A^{499}+A^{99}-Id= -4A^{-1}$?. wich it means that $A$ have inverse

Comment: I would rather say that $A.\frac14(\operatorname{Id}-A^{499}-A^{99})=\operatorname{Id}$, and that therefore $A^{-1}=\frac14(\operatorname{Id}-A^{499}-A^{99})$.

Answer (score 1):

A matrix is invertible if and only if the determinant is nonzero, which is true if and only if the constant term of the characteristic polynomial is nonzero.

Answer (score 1):

We have $p(0)=4 \ne 0$, hence $0$ is not an eigenvalue of $A$. Therefore $A$ is invertible.